# Trouble with RewriteCond in htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I need to do seems very simple, but for some reason I can't make it working.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/api/
```

I want all requests that are send to /api/(something) to be redirected to

/api/users/index.php

My whole  .htaccess file is

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/api/
RewriteRule ^ /api/users/index.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `RewriteCond` for this as the rule is very simple. Just use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^api/.* /api/users/index.php [L]
```

Make sure the `.htaccess` file is in the site's root directory

Comment: Thank you for the fast response.
I tryied that but it returns 500 error 


<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>

Comment: You need to look in the error logs. Most likely this will be a problem with your php code, but it could be config in the htacces file.

Comment: I changed my php file to a single

<?php
 header("http/1.1 404 bad");
?>
but I still got the 500 error, so I guess is something in the configuration.
How should I proceed solving it?

Thank you

Comment: The issue is I am not sure I am able to do that with my hosting.
I host with domainmonster